# How to call Google Map on Laravel view.blade

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, google-api

I am trying to use google map on the page but facing some trouble.
I used [this](https://github.com/alexpechkarev/google-maps) api, and installed it without a problem. I set the controller and route as below.

```
public function map()
{
    $response = \GoogleMaps::load('geocoding')
        ->setParam(['address' => 'tokyo'])
        ->get();

    return view('welcome', compact('response'));
}

Route::get('/', 'PagesController@map');
```

and calling the API into view.blade. I used just this:

```
{{ isset($response) ? $response : '' }}
```

Do I need to add some script too? Becouse I am getting this error;

> { "error_message" : "This API project is not authorized to use this
>   API.", "results" : [], "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED" }

or this error;

> /maps/api/place/add/json?key=AIzaSyDRA160KmwA5Z-7KZn_JfJRdSNkkSiqKRB
>   was not found on this server. That’s all we know.

What is the problem here? I double checked the API key. No problem with that. Already gave permission for my domain address too? What am I missing here?

And this is the some of config/googlemap.php file

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Key
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Will be used for all web services,
| unless overwritten bellow using 'key' parameter
|
|
*/

'key'       => 'AIzaSyDRA160KmwA5Z-7KZn_JfJRdSNkkSiqKRB',

/////

'geocoding' => [
            'url'                   => 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/',
            'type'                  => 'GET',
            'key'                   =>  null,
            'endpoint'              =>  true,
            'responseDefaultKey'    => 'place_id',
            'param'                 => [
                'address'       => null,
                'bounds'        => null,
                'key'           => null,
                'region'        => null,
                'language'      => null,
                'result_type'   => null,
                'location_type' => null,
                'latlng'        => null,
                'place_id'      => null,
                'components'    => [
                    'route'                 => null,
                    'locality'              => null,
                    'administrative_area'   => null,
                    'postal_code'           => null,
                    'country'               => null,
                ]
            ]
        ],
```

Comment: You haven't added any keys in googlemap.config file

Comment: @VineyHill no mate, i added updated the question. you can see it now.

Comment: I guess you should remove the `'key'                   =>  null,` from the 'geocoding' array in your config/googlemaps.php as it might be overrriding the one provided above.

Comment: @VineyHill i removed that completely but no effects at all

Comment: @VineyHill but when I try to make it "true" then error changes: `{ "error_message" : "The provided API key is invalid.", "results" : [], "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED" }` But my key is valid. I copy it from google console? how can it possible?